# get url from loaded image with picasso

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-recyclerview, picasso

how can i get url of loaded imgae with picasso and pass it to another activity in Recyclerview adapter????
.

i didnt find any thing for getting url from picasso so if anyone can help me please tell me a metod or a code for this action on this post ...thank you

```
package com.roa.nox.store.adapters;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.roa.nox.store.ApActivity;
import com.roa.nox.store.ItemObjectC;
import com.roa.nox.store.R;
import com.roa.nox.store.models.SingleItemModel;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import me.drakeet.materialdialog.MaterialDialog;

public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList;
    private Context mContext;
    private boolean isLang;


    public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);

        return mh;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

        SingleItemModel singleItem = itemsList.get(i);
        final int p= singleItem.getPrice();
        if(p==0)
        {
            if (isLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fa")) {
                holder.price.setText("رایگان");
            } else {
                holder.price.setText("Free");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(p));
        }
       double rate=singleItem.getRate();
       String srate= String.valueOf(rate);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());
        holder.dvt.setText(singleItem.getdv());
        holder.cat.setText(singleItem.getcat());
        holder.url.setText(singleItem.getUrl());
        holder.icon.setText(singleItem.geticon());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(singleItem.geticon()).placeholder(R.drawable.load).error(R.drawable.error).into(holder.itemImage);
        holder.cont.setText(singleItem.getContent());


        holder.rte.setText(srate);


       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected ImageButton btaction;
        protected TextView rte;
        protected TextView cat;
        protected TextView price;
        protected TextView tvTitle;
        protected TextView dvt;
        protected TextView url;
        protected TextView icon;
        protected TextView cont;
        protected ImageView itemImage;
        private Context context;

        private int p;

        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            this.dvt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tdv);
            this.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            this.url = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);
            this.cont = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            this.btaction = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.action);
            this.rte = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.raten);
            this.cat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat);
            this.icon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);





            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                public ItemObjectC parseImageFile;
                public String iconi;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final String URL = url.getText().toString();

                    final int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ApActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", tvTitle.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("price", price.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("content", cont.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("dev", dvt.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("cat", cat.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("icon", What i should to add for get url???);
                    intent.putExtra("rate", rte.getText().toString());
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);


                }
            });


            btaction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup,
                            popup.getMenu());
                    popup.show();
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.install:



                                    break;
                                case R.id.addtowishlist:


                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });




        }

    }}
```

Comment: You do not get the URL from Picasso. You give the URL to Picasso, so it knows what to load. If you want to pass that URL to something else, you need to track the URL yourself, such as having it be part of your model data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without modifying Picasso library yourself. Fortunately, there is commonly used and easy to implement work-around. Simply, tag your clickable element with your item's id/position. For example (if holder.itemImage is clickable), in onBindViewHolder():

```
holder.itemImage.setTag(position);
```

Then, in onClick() or wherever you handle clicks:

```
int position = (int) v.getTag();
String iconUrl = adapter.itemsList.get(position).geticon(); // make itemsList public or provide getter first
```

Comment: If you really want, you can put the actual URL into the tag.

Comment: Sure, but I think it's convenient to have access to whole item.

Comment: I sometimes put the whole item as a tag. It is useful when for example the Activity is handling the onClick, and you want to avoid accessing the adapter to get the item.

Answer (score 0):

you can make setter like this :

```
        holder.setImage(Arraylist<String> array ,Int position) {

        Arraylist<String> url = new Arraylist<String>();
        url = array.get(position);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(image_view); }
```

and in your method :

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {
...
holder.setImage(your_array,i);
...
}
```